# How does ShareIt create and configure hotspot

Tags: android, wifimanager, hotspot

I have to create a **Wifi Hotspot** with specific **SSID** and **PASSWORD** dynamically in my Android app project. I checked the ShareIt mobile app which creates a hotspot with **SSID** and **PASSWORD** and the receiver will connect to that hotspot, am expecting something similar to that.

Requirement is like, **Android app** should be able to create the **Wifi hotspot** with specific **SSID** and **PASSWORD** which will get from the server.

```
 WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = null;
try {
    wificonfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
    wificonfiguration.SSID = apName;
    // if WiFi is on, turn it off
    if(isApOn(context)) {
        wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        // if ap is on and then disable ap
        disableAp(context);
    }
    Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
    method.invoke(wifimanager, wificonfiguration, true);
    return true;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried this code snippet, which is gives a `NoSuchMethodException` error.

Checking for **Android version 9 Pie**

Answer (score 0):

App like ShareIt is creating hotspot using [Local Only Hotspot](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/localonlyhotspot)

But in this case android is creating hotspot with a ssid and password that we cannot configure (Android is choosing a random ssid and password)